# how to block access to include(x_file) from a file in a certain folder?

Tags: php, include, require-once

I have a folder that contains many different files:

**folder1:**

```
somthing.php
somthingelse.php
blah.php
ect ect....
```

Now, I don't want the files in that folder to access (include) files outside the folder. So it's okay to `include('blah.php'`) but not okay to `include('../blah.php')`..

Any ideas on how I'd go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible on the CLI and in a Unix environment. You would have to use `chroot` to hide other folders.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chroot.php